# Handling textarea input inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I have `textarea` and `button` inside a `ngFor`. I want to call a function on `button` click with the value entered in the textarea. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                <textarea  placeholder="Enter value" rows="5"
                 matInput maxlength="150" [(ngModel)]="inputText"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

For the `textarea` I have done `[(ngModel)]="inputText"`. Now since `inputText` is same everywhere, even if I type in one field, all the fields show the same text.

**Solution I came up with**

I can add a new field in the items and bind using `[(ngModel)]="item.enteredValue"`. But this items list is large and it comes from the server, and therefore I do not want to add an additional field into it, which is not required.

Is there some other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your items have unique identifiers, you can do:

**Component**

```js
// define an empty object
inputText = {}

onSubmit(itemId: string) {
  submit(inputText[itemId]);
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <!-- bind to a value of the object using the items id -->
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="inputText[item.id]"></textarea>
  <button (click)="onSubmit(item.id)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively you can reuse the item itself as @awe pointed out.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="item.myText"></textarea>
  <button (click)="onSubmit(item.myText)">Submit</button>
</div>

// in your component
onSubmit(text: string) {
  submit(text);
}
```

Comment: Using the item unique id was also my first thought. I think this is the best approach. It will work perfectly unless there is also functionality here in the same list to add new items to the items list that will get items with no unique id.

Comment: That works perfectly for the returned values in array.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                <textarea  placeholder="Enter value" rows="5"
                 matInput maxlength="150" [(ngModel)]="inputTexts[i]"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onSubmit(inputTexts[i])">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you just need an array `inputTexts: string[] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

You say you do not want to add new field to the model, but you don't actually need to add the field to the source model. When binding how you did it with `[(ngModel)]="item.enteredValue"` the field is added dynamically on the javascript item object, and available for your client side javascript code when you submit. Then you can read the values from each item in the items list, and use it how you intend. Even though the javascript item objects now contain the `enteredValue` field, it does not need to be part of the original data model coming from the server.

Comment: Agreed, but I need to send the response back as well to the server on submit. I will need to remove the additional field in that case.

Comment: I came up with another alternative but not sure if it is right approach, although it works. Could you please confirm? 
`<textarea  placeholder="Enter value" rows="5"
     matInput maxlength="150" #input></textarea>`

`<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onSubmit(input)">Submit</button>`

In the function, I simply extract the value by `input.value`,

Comment: Wouldn't this create multiple `texarea`s with the same id `input`, as you create the `textarea`s in an `*ngFor`?

Comment: @helloworld If you do not have this field in the data model, where will you store it? What are you using it for when you submit?